# How load a PHP page in the same window in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file, Test.php, and it has two functions:

```
<?php
    echo displayInfo();
    echo displayDetails();
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<html>
     ...
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: 'display.php',
            data:'id='+id  ,
            success: function(data){
                $("#response").html(data);
            }
        });
    </script>
    ...

    <div id="response">
    </div>
</html>
```

It returns the response from jQuery. The response shows as `<a href=Another.php?>Link</a>`. When I click the Another.php link in `test.php`, it loads in another window. But I need it to load the same `<div> </div>` area without changing the content of `test.php`, since it has `displayInfo(), displayDetails()`. Or is it possible to load a PHP page inside `<div> </div>` elements?

How can I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like for the `a` link to cancel navigation, but fire the AJAX function?

In that case:

```
$("#mylink").click(function() {
    $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "another.php", data: {id: "somedata"}, function(data) {
        $("#response").html(data);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [MooTools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MooTools) and class [Request.HTML](http://mootools.net/docs/Request/Request.HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Krof is correct,

One possible unwanted behavior of this however is that it will query the data every time the link is clicked.  You can set the event to only call the ajax query once by using one.

```
$("#mylink").one('click', function() {
  // ajax call
  return false;
});
```

Don't forget to set href="javascript:{}" in your link so after the event is fired once the link wont do anything;

Comment: Actually the `href=""` part isn't needed if you cancel event bubbling by returning `false`. Although I think it does help if you want to avoid having the outline drawn around `a` elements (if I remember correctly).